# Adding icon in Android ToolBar

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-toolbar

I have two activities

- MainActivity
- DetailActivity

My MainActivity.xml has AppBarLayout and Toolbar elements.
In Main Activity.java, I set the icon in toolbar using:

```
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
// setting icon
getSupportActionBar().setIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
```

This same line of code is not working for Detail activity.
Detail Activity has the toolbar by default. I can set the title in toolbar as well using:

```
getSupportActionBar().setTitle(String title);
```

But, I am unable to set Icon in Detail Activity using:

```
getSupportActionBar().setIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

<application
    android:name=".App"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity
        android:name=".apod_main"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".apod_detail"></activity>
</application>
```

**Build Configs:**

**Android API** 26
**Build Tools Version** 26.0.1

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try this:

```
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);  
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
getSupportActionBar().setIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
```

Comment: Thank You! 
This worked for me.

`getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);`    
`getSupportActionBar().setIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);`

Comment: Be aware that `getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(boolean);` might produce `NullPointerException` preform null checking before using it.

Comment: @Yupi, to avoid the null pointer exception, place the commands in the onPrepareOptionsMenu method.

Comment: And how we can add click listener into this icon?

Answer (score 3):

**try this if you want to add back arrow in your actionbar**

```
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
getSupportActionBar().setIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
```

Comment: _(Oct 2020)_ Because I want to add my app icon instead of back arrow, I had to add as the very first line `getSupportActionBar().setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);` before these 2 lines; the last line was not needed then.